# Delegating user permission to backend service using OAuth 2.0

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I am trying to understand how to securely delegate user permissions between layers of my application, following best practices. Protocol used is OAuth 2.0.

I tried to capture the scenario on diagram below. Application "my app" consists of two layers:

- Single Page Application,
- API.

User of my application wishes to browse through files on external service (3) and eventually request application to pull some of the files from the service (5). The first part does not pose any problems, but I am not sure how to securely obtain/pass the access token for API to interact further with the service on behalf of the user (5).

The simplest approach I can think of: pass the token from (2) in the request to API (4), so it can be used in step (5). On one hand it makes sense, as the token (2) was obtained providing "My app" application ID. On the other hand, it "feels not right", as the token is a secret and I something tells me that it should not leave user browser.

What is the right and secure approach for delegating the permissions to the API?

Regards,
Artur
[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something in your description, (5) is a completely intended use case of the token when Microsoft issued it to the user.

Comment: Hey @ricardkelly, thanks for response. Microsoft indeed issued the token, the request contained "My app" application ID. If I understand you correctly, you believe that sending that token to "My app" API would be intended use case?

Comment: Yes, the token is intended for your application to use to access APIs as the identity, scoped to the permission set the token was created with.

Comment: More information on the process intended to be followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online